# React Boostrap Icon

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

```
import { BsFillTrashFill } from "react-icons/bs";
                   <button
                      className="btnRemove"
                      onClick={this.handleRemove}
                      value={data.cId}
                    >
                      <BsFillTrashFill value={data.cId} size="30px" />
                    </button>
```

is react bootstrap icon. When I click the button where cover by SVG, the target will become , the value becomes undefine. I just want to return the target value when I click the button.

Answer (score 0):

If you use create-react-app 2.0 you can now do it like this:

```
import { ReactComponent as YourSvg } from './your-svg.svg';
```

And then use it just like you would normally use a component: